# problem with state update onChange method in a select form , React Component

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hooks, use-state

Im updating a Table component, depending on the value of the Select on a Form, what i want to do is to update the Table immediatly after y choose a selection on my form, what im doing is this

```
const [value,setValue] = useState(null)
const handleChanges = (e) =>{
    setValue(e.target.value);
    updateTable(value)  // this is not assigned after handleChanges 
    console.log(value) // null      
}
<select onChange={handleChanges}>
   <option> 1 </option> 
   <option> 2 </option>
   <option> 3 </option>
</select>
```

if someone can help me and explain the better way to solve it.

i solved it  passing the e.target.value instead value, but i feel is not the best option

```
const handleChanges = (e) =>{
setValue(e.target.value);
updateTable(e.target.value)  // i should use value
console.log(e.target.value) // 1 or 2 or 3 depending on option
```

}

Comment: `useState()` is asynchronous, thats why it doesn't get updated  immediately

Comment: i know that is async , what will be the best solution, hooks dont support callback as a second parameter

Comment: SOLVED, useEffect is the best solution